# $C^k_c(\mathbb{D})$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis

For a domain $\mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a function, $f$, that is $k$-differentiable in the domain is $C^k(\mathbb{D})$ differentiable, or $f\in C^k(\mathbb{D})$. In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#For_bounded_open_subsets_of_Euclidean_space) proof, what does $C^k_c(\mathbb{D})$ denote with the subscript $c$? Further, what resources introduce terms like this and $L^k$ (integrable) functions? I have only seen them used, never actually introduced as a stand-alone concept.

Comment: Usually compact support.